# Why is my model.reload() in afterModel redirecting to a related model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

For some reason calling `model.reload()` in my `afterModel` is redirecting to a related model's route, and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
SkillRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @store.find('skill', {slug: params.slug}).then (model) =>
      model.get('firstObject')
  afterModel: (model) ->
    model.reload() # offending line
```

(The `firstObject` is simply using `Ember.Enumerable` to retrieve the first skill in a one item array. Calling `.toString()` here - and in the `afterModel` - would reveal this is a `: model:skill::ember659:1`)

This transitions to the `RecipeRoute` for some reason, wherein a `Recipe` is the parent for the `Skill`, e.g.

```
Recipe = DS.Model.extend
  skills: DS.hasMany('skill', {async: true})
```

This redirection is not intended. Rather, I am intending to re-request data as the `Recipe` includes a partially serialized version of `Skill` to reduce database lookups, response size, etc.

Comment: What route?  Is it crashing?  Can you show the route?

Comment: The `SkillRoute` transitions to `RecipeRoute`. It's pretty standard, with `model` just implementing `@store.find('recipe', params.recipe_id)`.

Comment: Will you show the other route and router

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be unrelated to the change I was making. The `link-to 'skill'` that should have transitioned from the `RecipesRoute` to the `SkillRoute` was contained within an `Ember.View` which handled a `click` event.

While this `click` event strangely did not fire without the `model.reload()` in the `afterModel` (which still baffles me), I finally prevented it by adding `bubbles=false` to my `link-to`.